# Why LinkedHashSet does not support index based operation as it maintain order of it's element

Tags: java, collections

Why LinkedHashSet does not support index operation as it maintain order of it's element.

As we know, LinkedHashSet is implementation of Set interface which maintain order of it's element. So, My question is as it is already maintaining order of the elements why it don't provide index based operation.

Comment: `SortedSet` doesn't either. Nor `ArrayDeque`, although IIRC Josh Bloch thinks it was a mistake for that not to implement `List`. There's an obvious random access argument, but then there's `LinkedList` (it just doesn't implement `RandomAccess`).